# Hard drive health

Tags: hard-drive, overheating, case-layout

So some quick information. I have 4 hdds and one ssd in my custom build. I also have two hard drive bays in my pc and both can hold up to 4 drives stacked above each other. I can remove the top drive bay to allow more airflow and room for gpus if I need to.

None of the gpus im looking to buy will fit in my case with the top drive bay installed.

So my question is if I remove the top drive bay and place all my hdds in the bottom bay will that damage them in the long run?

Concidering 2 of my hard drives are from older pcs and 1 puts off quite a bit of heat. As opposed to having them spaced out between 2 drive bays which I would prefer but wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try to do just that (without buying the graphics card first) and take a look at temperature, you could use [crystal disk](https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjema7zqobOAhXHXRQKHSd-CpsQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcrystalmark.info%2Fsoftware%2FCrystalDiskInfo%2Findex-e.html&usg=AFQjCNGYBcnUPItbmXP7Ao3Lilao7xPVJg) for that. Eventually try adding some degrees to your true result, to simulate, the gpu additional temperature.